# How to specify to install oracle jdk instead of openjdk in sdk cli on ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: java, ubuntu, sdkman

When using [sdkman](http://sdkman.io/) on uBuntu 17.04, I do not see an option to install the oracle jdk. How to specify to install oracle jdk using [sdkman](http://sdkman.io/) on uBuntu 17.04?

```
$sdk list java
 ===================================================================
 Available Java Version
 ===================================================================
 > * 8u131-zulu                                                                    
     7u141-zulu                                                                    
     6u93-zulu 


 ===================================================================
 + - local version
 * - installed
 > - currently in use
 ===================================================================
$
```

Comment: Oracle JDK used to be there. I am not sure why it is no longer supported. OpenJDK is not an option for us.

Comment: Yeah, it was removed due to the fact that oracle 6 & 7 needs oracle support account login to download. However, oracle java 8 does not, lets hope that they will get back oracle jdk option for latest version.

Comment: Here is the [post](https://medium.com/@sdkman_/about-proprietary-jdks-on-sdkman-6052525a152e) related to it.

Comment: [github issue](https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-cli/issues/543) for the reference!

Comment: It started supporting `java 8`, please check the output of `sdk list java`

Comment: @RishikeshDarandale `sdk list java` and `sdk ls java` are the same command, aliased.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can type `sdk ls java` and see which versions are available.

At the moment I see `8u141-oracle` in the list. So you can install it by `sdk i java 8u141-oracle`

Comment: Thanks @Derp. I already specified in my comments that it started supporting the Oracle java.

Comment: @RishikeshDarandale If the available answer is satisfactory, consider marking it as accepted.

Answer (score 12):

Just for anyone stumbling upon this answer:
You can still download Oracle JDK and extract it manually in the appropriate folder. After that you can use all the sdkman commands like if it was installed automatically.

Extract Oracle JDK to `~/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.241-oracle` and activate using `sdk use java 8.0.241-oracle`.

2021 Edit:
You no longer need to install/extract the manually downloaded binaries in the `.sdkman` folder. Just use `local-path` and provide the path where the binaries reside, e.g.
`sdk install groovy 2.4.13-local /opt/groovy-2.4.13`

Comment: How do you that for the Mac? There is only a dmg package available, not a zip, which one should I use? I tried 1 of the linux tar zips, but it doesn't work (Eclipse doesn't recognize it)

Comment: @edbras I would install the oracle jdk with the dmg file, look up the location where it is installed and symlink to the appropriate sdkman candidates folder. I think this is the only way because I am not aware of a way to tell sdkman *where* something is installed. There is only the one default install location.

Comment: This should be the top and accepted answer...and I really appreciated it. Now I can still use the version management SDKMAN provides with Oracle java. Splendid :)

Comment: Works fine with Java 11, this should be the accepted answer :)

Comment: This script helped me for the first part https://gist.github.com/smola/b1332103514a7834cabca6af7bb09ceb

Answer (score 11):

Currently Oracle JDKs has finally been pulled out from SDKMAN due to some legal issues. The legal issues are explained over [here](https://medium.com/@sdkman_/about-proprietary-jdks-on-sdkman-6052525a152e)

They have decided to introduce a lot of OpenJDK implementations like Azul Zulu, Azul ZuluFX for those who need JavaFX along with it. Please check with `sdk ls java` to find out what more are supported as of now.

Comment: the more relevant answer now is provided here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/60346121/6389169

Comment: hmm, oracle is listed in the CLI at the moment.