# Can I install a previous version of a JDK with sdkman?

Tags: sdkman

sdkman lists the current Corretto JDK version (8.282.08.1-amzn) and I can install that. Is it possible to install a previous version (8.275.01.1) with sdkman as well? If so, how can I list the previous versions available?

Answer (score 5):

Following up on [JSamir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1189810/jsamir) and [the answer they linked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60346121/399105), here's what I did specifically to install an older version of Azul Zulu (I prefer it to Corretto because they provide non-LTS versions and optionally bundle JavaFX, but adjust these instructions as needed):

1. Download the version of Java you'd like to install

   - In my case, since I want to download an old version of Azul Zulu, I can see all the old versions here: https://cdn.azul.com/zulu/bin/
   - I downloaded this one: https://cdn.azul.com/zulu/bin/zulu8.40.0.25-ca-jdk8.0.222-linux_x64.tar.gz
2. Extract to ~/.sdkman/candidates/java/, e.g.

   ```
   tar xvf zulu8.40.0.25-ca-jdk8.0.222-linux_x64.tar.gz
   mv zulu8.40.0.25-ca-jdk8.0.222-linux_x64 ~/.sdkman/candidates/java/8.0.222-zulu
   ```
3. Tell SDKMAN to use the version you downloaded

   - Just this shell

     ```
     sdk use java 8.0.222-zulu
     ```
   - Use it as the default for all shells

     ```
     sdk default java 8.0.222-zulu
     ```

Answer (score 0):

With the work within this issue, the base for such a feature is there:
https://github.com/sdkman/sdkman-db-migrations/issues/170

But it is not implemented yet, e.g. there are no commands for the sdkman cli to install older versions.

Until such a feature is implemented, I would manually download older versions and install them locally. Afterwards, you can switch to this version with the sdkman commands as if that version was installed with sdkman. For details see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60346121/1189810

Answer (score 0):

As the offical documentation says:https://sdkman.io/usage

> Install Local Version(s)
> Using a snapshot version? Already have a local installation? Setup a local version by specifying the path to the local installation:

So, download the java version you need,  set it up on your system an then run:

```
sdk install java localname /path/to/jvm/you/just/installed
```

> `sdk install java 17-zulu /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-17.jdk/Contents/Home`

Sdk lets you use it.